# What type of filter is this?

Tags: c++, filtering, sensors

```
output = (((previous * rate) + current) / (rate + 1.0))
```

I believe it's a low pass, but correct me if I'm wrong. Is there a more accurate way to describe a function like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a low pass filter, with an Infinite Impulse Response design. The rate is used to determine how much a single new value can change the output. A large rate puts more value on the previous state, and less on the current value.

Consider when rate is 1: `output` is 1/2 of the `previous` value plus 1/2 of the `current` value. In other words, it's the average of the two.

When rate is larger, `output` is more heavily weighted to the `previous` value, so high-frequency variations in subsequent values of `current` are filtered out, and only slow changes to `current` affect the `output`.